# How to scale components with windows javafx?

Tags: javafx-2, transformation, tabpanel

[image: tabpane menu]

My windows primary pane is an `AnchorPane` on top of which is a `TabPane`, the menu of that `TabPane` are the tabs you see on the picture. You see the grey "background" which is part of the `TabPane`, when I scale my window to a bigger size, the `TabPane` doesn't scale with it, it stays the same size, so extra space is blank, I would like it to scale with the window, in the width of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell the `AnchorPane` to anchor its child (the `TabPane`) so that it is resized automatically when the window size changes.

If you are using Scene Builder you can achieve this by selecting the `TabPane`, going to the layout section of the properties window and setting the anchor properties.

[image]

Click on each of the dotted lines until it looks like the image below.

[image]

The same effect can also be set in code using the `setXXXAnchor` methods of the `AnchorPane`:

```
pane.setLeftAnchor(tabPane, 0.0);
pane.setRightAnchor(tabPane, 0.0);
pane.setTopAnchor(tabPane, 0.0);
pane.setBottomAnchor(tabPane, 0.0);
```